# Appengine won't display Python function

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a really simple program that checks the date and returns if the combined *month+day+year* is a so called ***happy number*** (a number whos sum of the square of its digits equal one) or not.
The program works fine when I run it locally through python but when I try to run it through the appengine, either locally or online, nothing is displayed but a single TEST print line.
I can't figure out why the appengine will not display the function.

Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated as I'm stuck.
The appengine logs show a GET request:

```
" INFO     2011-04-14 18:19:14,981 dev_appserver.py:3317] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -"
```

but nothing afterwards.

```
import sys
import datetime

def main():
    date = datetime.date.today()
    datearray=[0,0,0]
    datearray[0]=str(date.month)
    datearray[1]=str(date.day)
    datearray[2]=str(date.year)
    joined = ''.join(datearray)
    print "Date:",int(joined)
    print happynums(int(joined))

def happynums(num):
    total = int(num)
    varnum = 0
    bin=0    
    x=0
    past=set()

    while total!=1:
        if total in past:
            return "Sad day :("
        past.add(total)
        list = map(int,str(total))
        total=0
        for i in list:
            total = total + i**2
        if total==1:
            return "Happy day :)"

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
    print "TEST"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't simply `print` to `stdout` in a CGI script; you must first send headers followed by a blank line. Your output is being interpreted by your browser as HTTP headers and isn't printing.

You almost certainly want to be using some kind of WSGI framework to handle this for you.

Comment: Thank you! I plan on diving into Django but wanted to at least know the program was running correctly online first.

Comment: You could use `import logging` , `logging.debug("Happy day")` if you're just looking to check functionality.